# How do you get Jupyter Notebook-like auto completion on VS code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, jupyter-notebook

When using Juputer Notebooks I can press `tab` to get a list of methods/attributes of previously evaluated objects.

[image]

Is there something similar in VS code?

Comment: VSC is an editor, it does not execute Python code you edit, any runtime generated methods and fields are not found compared to REPL-IDLE

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to use VS code so as to get this functionality? E.g. evaluating part of my code through its notebook plugging?